# Windows Workflow Code Activity Property Order

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

Is there an attribute or something I can use to define what order properties appear in the visual studio property editor for my custom activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Category attribute to group them but AFAIK you can't sort them inside of a category group.

Comment: Sounds like thats as close as I'll get. At least it's a little easier to manage now, thanks.